# How to mark embedded document for destruction with mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

In ActiveRecord we have `mark_for_destruction` method which works perfectly with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

I want to remove and add a bunch of embedded documents after validation succeed with a single save command of parent document.
How this can be done with Mongoid?

Comment: Did you have a look at http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/nested_attributes.html

Comment: @rubish Thanks. Already done it through nested attributes.

Comment: Hey are there any updates with recent versions of Mongoid ? I need to clean up an array of embedded records and some have validation errors. I'd like to clean all of those in one go.